# Node.js "ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED"

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, dll, build

I'm sorta new to Node, and I'm trying to build [this tetris AI project](https://github.com/GregoryCannon/StackRabbit) from source, and when trying to build, it runs gyp fine and all but hit a wall and ends like this.

```
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I have attempted other answers such as deleting and re-`npm install`ing but no luck.

Here is what I tried.

```
PS C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit> npm run start
```

Node gyp works just fine, and we get to this point:

```
> stackrabbit@1.0.0 start
> node built/src/server/app.js
```

Until it crashes and burns with a big long list of failures:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\build\Release\cRabbit.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\built\src\server\worker_thread.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\build\Release\cRabbit.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\built\src\server\worker_thread.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\build\Release\cRabbit.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\built\src\server\worker_thread.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\build\Release\cRabbit.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\built\src\server\worker_thread.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\build\Release\cRabbit.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\built\src\server\worker_thread.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\build\Release\cRabbit.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\built\src\server\worker_thread.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\build\Release\cRabbit.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\344agg21\Downloads\repos\StackRabbit\built\src\server\worker_thread.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Anyone have any clue if this is an issue with the code, or me missing something? All packages are installed for npm and node-gyp gets going just fine. It's a really cool project I wanted to experiment with but it seems I am missing something critical, and I have had no luck with google or digging through what it does to throw this error. I'm probably just stupid and suck at building from source code but I don't know. Anyone with experience on building from source or Node.js and that stuff please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, because I don't have a clue why it's failing or how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. remove the build, built, and node_modules folders
2. **run powershell as administrator**
3. npm update
4. npm install
5. npm run start-server (ignore errors)
6. npm run start

These steps worked for me. However, I am still unable to run the Fceux lua script client on Windows even after recompiling it.